# Alternative Mac drivers for Samsung printers?

Tags: mac, drivers, printer, ppc

Are there any alternative Mac drivers for Samsung printers?
I've got an old (2003) Samsung ML-1510. The only Mac driver available requires Rosetta (PPC emulation) to get installed.
According to various news sites, Mac OS 10.7 will drop Rosetta. So I'm looking for alternative drivers. I checked [Gutenprint](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php) but the ML-1510 isn't in the list of supported printers.

Do you happen to know an alternative other than buying a new printer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this driver: http://guigo.us/mac/splix/

Works well wih my Samsung ML-1510 on OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: Not tested, but according to you and the documentation this seems to be the right solution. Thanks a lot for answering this old question!

Answer (score 1):

I use an old ML-1610 on OSX and am in a similar boat I think. I can't check right now (not at home), but I found some third party driver (probably Gutenprint) and got it working by trying a few different printer models with mine. So in the worst case, you may luck out finding a driver for some other printer model compatible "enough" for your purposes.

An alternative would be to set up some kind of print server using older, but fully compatible software. You could do it as a VM or use an old computer. That said, the modern versions of Samsung's printers that compete with your model are fairly inexpensive too. But you're probably like me, unwilling to throw out hardware that's otherwise completely functional for your needs.

Comment: Yes I saw that the ML-2525 doesn't cost that much. But indeed I don't want to throw away an otherwise fine working device. I'll give some of the Gutenprint drivers a try. Thanks for your anwer.

Comment: Yup, I hear ya with the not tossing decent hardware - same situation as me. Granted, if it takes you 10 hours to get it working, that may be a serious waste. You could always put your old one up on Kijiji for cheap.. But yeah, please post back if you find a decent driver fit.

Comment: So tried most of the Samsung Gutenprint drivers but none worked. I've ordered a new Samsung ML-2851ND for 180$ now which will be quite a nice upgrade with its duplex feature and network interface. Anyway the toner of the old printer will be empty soon.

Comment: Well, perhaps your old printer can find new purpose as a hackaday project?